# What do I say when two different companies that I am interested in working in both schedule an interview at the same date and time?

Tags: interviewing

I sent copies of my CV to multiple companies with job openings online and I got a call from one of them from a company that I was interested in working in for a scheduled interview. I confirmed my attendance to the said interview, but then a couple of days later this other company that I also was interested in working in sent a text message also inviting me to an interview, but on the same date and time as the first one.

I wanted to attend both interviews so that in case I get rejected by one, I could still have a chance with the other. I don't know if it's even right to do that, to attend multiple interviews to get a higher chance of getting hired, but if it is, how should I respond to the second company if we could reschedule the interview?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace! I have seen that you have already accepted an answer very quickly after your question was posted. In that specific case that may be fine, but in general it is advised to wait a bit longer (typically about 1 to 2 days) to mark an answer as accepted. This is due to the fact that we want some competition between answers with the best answer being accepted. Accepting an answer early often keeps other people away from writing an additional, maybe even better answer. As said, in this rather clear case it might be OK but consider waiting a bit more to accept in future cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with attending multiple interviews, it's actually a good idea to do so.

Ask the second company to reschedule due to a prior commitment you have on the arranged time/date. This shouldn't create an issue, most companies have some leeway and can shuffle interviews around to suit.

This is best done more personally than a text message, either a phone call or at the very least an email. There is no need to go into details, a prior commitment is a fair enough reason.

Something like "Thank you for the opportunity, but unfortunately I have a prior commitment at that time on the xx/xx/xxxx. Can you please reschedule either to a later/earlier time on that day, I will be unavailable between Z and Y, but any time apart from that would be fine, or perhaps a different day etc,."

Comment: This is extremely helpful information. Thank you very much for this! I really appreciate it! Have a great day!

Comment: Right.  I would add if they are inflexible about an interview schedule, do they really want to hire you? do you really want to work for them?

Comment: I'd actually say "... but unfortunately I have already another interview scheduled at the same time". Doesn't hurt if they know about another interview, and they won't be wondering why you think an interview is less important than "a prior commitment".

Comment: that can go two ways, unless they're desperate then you're basically telling them that they are your second choice. I wouldn't try little mind games like that in a buyers market.